# How can I build a map of non-geographical data?

Tags: data-visualization, opengl, visual-design

https://jef.works/MERmaid/
I want to visualize biological data similar to this that is much larger in scale (several tiles, millions of dots in various genes).

I really like the maps for OpenStreetMap and Leaflet.js or Uber's kepler.gl. Is there any way to use data that isn't a traditional map with these? Or how do you advise building it up from scratch?